# Sorting out List and printing the selected values

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 3D list with the length 17 x 100000 x 4. 
Something like this:

```
AtIndxList[1][0]=['321','26.5','33.6','-56.5']
```

I need to select those lists for which `AtIndxList[i][j][1] > -31.25` and `< 31.25` and `AtIndxList[i][j][2] > -31.25` and `< 31.25` and `AtIndxList[i][j][2] > -31.25` and `< 31.25`

I tried the following

```
for i in range(1,17):
    for j in range (1, 100000):
        if (AtIndxList[i][j][1]>-31.25 and AtIndxList[i][j][1]<31.25 and AtIndxList[i][j][2]>-31.25 and AtIndxList[i][j][2]<31.25 and  AtIndxList[i][j][3]>-31.25 and AtIndxList[i][j][3]<31.25):
            print AtIndxList[i][j][0]
```

But somehow it is not printing those selected lists. Is there any other efficient way to make this selection ? I would appreciate if somehow I can get rid of the "if" statement because it would make the computation bit slower.

Comment: `AtIndxTuple[1][0]=['321','26.5','33.6','-56.5']` it is a list, not `tuple`

Comment: thanks for the correction.

Comment: I think iterate time for lists is O(n) . How shapeable is that data source ? Can you make changes to it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
AtIndxList[1][0]=['321','26.5','33.6','-56.5']
```

it is a list of strings, while you trying to compare elements with float

My suggetstion:

Introduce next function:

```
def check_me(el, i, j):
    return next(iter(set(
        [el[i][j][x] > -31.25 and el[i][j][x] < 31.25
        for x in range(1, 4)]
        ))
    )
```

It will return `True` or `False` according to your conditional.

```
>>> print check_me([[[321,26.5,30.6,-16.5]]], 0, 0)
>>> print check_me([[[321,26.5,30.6,-56.5]]], 0, 0)
True
False

[el[i][j][x] > -31.25 and el[i][j][x] < 31.25 for x in range(1, 4)]
```

will produce list `[True, True, True]` for each element, next we will unify that list, after that we just unpack value from `set`.

Nice trick if there is any `False` it will be always first, see:

```
>>> set([True, False])
set([False, True])
```

Comment: perhaps it was a typo or he will cast to float ?

Comment: Thanks for  the answers. After xi_'s comment I tried converting the strings to float while comparing and it worked.

Comment: It would be even better if you managed to cast the whole list to float before the comparisons.

Comment: It's worth noting that inequalities can be chained to condense the code: `31.25 > el[i][j][x] > -31.25`. Also, since the inequalities are symmetric here, `abs` might be relevant: `abs(el[i][j][x]) < 31.25`

Comment: @x_i yes that resolves my problem. But now I am trying to figure out how to make a list of list of list for the selected `AtIndxList[i][j][0]`

Comment: Is it possible to append `AtIndxList[i][j][0]` in a 3D list after the selection ?

Comment: Yes. But before you need initialize i, j with empty lists. Maybe accept answer?  :)